# OSX Pages - How to use roman numeral page numbers for introduction and decimal numbers for remaining paper

Tags: macos, iwork-pages

Apologies if this has been posted - it's hard to find anything with "Pages" as the title of the program

**I need to use roman numerals for the first five or six introductory pages, then switch over and start from '1, 2..'. Using Mac OSX Pages, how can one accomplish this?** I've tried putting section breaks and layout breaks, but either I'm doing this step wrong or I'm missing the real way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Switch into outline view, and make sure your document is broken up into sections you desire. Every time you want to reset your page number, or change the style, you'll need a new section.

Open up inspector. Under Layout > Sections, check 'Starts at: 1', and uncheck 'Use previous headers & footers'. Finally, when inserting an auto page number, make sure the dropdown for Show In is by section, not document.

Answer (score 0):

The you need to highlight that page number and right-click (or control-click if you have the Apple single-button mouse) and an option should pop up allowing you to choose a, b, c,  or   i, ii, iii,  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after researching this I find that the answers I came across were not 100% complete, so to help another person out, here is the answer if the answers above don't work for you.

You want to go to the "Document" part of the Inspector.  Click on "Section."  Then select to enter page number.  The only numbers I got at first were Arabic, so just click on an Arabic number.  Then after you have inserted the Arabic page number, you get a drop down list of Roman numerals as well as Arabic numbers.  Don't know why they do this, but I was about to pull my hair out until I figured this out.